# Multiple iframe windows with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a webpage with four columns, all holding hidden iFrames. When you click one of the four buttons the content for that button will show. In these iFrames are forms that increase in height when hidden fields are displayed.

I've tried using this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function iframeLoaded() {
          var iFrameID = document.querySelectorAll("#iframe1, #iframe2, #iframe3, #iframe4"));
          if(iFrameID) {
                iFrameID.height = "1900px";
                iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
          }   
      }
    </script>
```

And here is one of my iFrames:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="#" id="iframe1" onload="iframeLoaded()" allowtransparency="true" style="width:100%;height:1900px;border:none;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

How can I make each of my iFrames height dynamic based on the forms height?

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over each frame individually:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var frame = document.getElementById("frame" + i);
    frame.style.height = "1900px";
    frame.style.height = contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```